Why is Afrikaans Keyboard randomly installed on Windows 11?
I've done some searching and this seems to be a common problem. It is not included under settings in my list of languages and keyboards, but when I installed another language it magically appeared. I never used Afrikaans or any app that uses Afrikaans. This is a new laptop. I have English and Chinese Simplified keyboards installed.

Here is another duplicate of this question. This is another duplicate

Here is an article that contains a correct solution. Other people edit registry keys and do other unnecessary unsafe system changes. This works much better.
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/the-afiikaans-keyboard-layout-is-automatically/71d635e0-472b-4e03-b440-52e801ab97e5

Press Start then search Powershell
Right Click then Run as administrator
Paste the command below then hit Enter:
$UserLanguage = New-WinUserLanguageList en-US
After that, Paste the command below then hit Enter:
Set-WinUserLanguageList $UserLanguage

(Answer from John DeV)
I found that restarting the machine is unnecessary.
In the $UserLanguage = New-WinUserLanguageList en-US portion, one can supply the languages in comma-separated format
eg, $UserLanguage = New-WinUserLanguageList en-US,es-MX

Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.

Which one of the numerous responses in that thread worked?

I did this by quoting the locales and putting spaces in between like $UserLanguage = New-WinUserLanguageList "en-US ja-JP" and it also worked for me. I logged out and back in and it was ok. Remember to run the second command after Set-WinUserLanguageList $UserLanguage -- Edit: I also didn't run powershell as admin and it worked so maybe it's not needed if you don't have multiple users
